# nlohmann/json uWebsocket

Tags: c++, json, websocket

For a project I am want to use the `uNetworking/uWebSockets` library in combination with the `nlohmann/json` library.

This is my code so far:

```
#include <uWS/uWS.h>
using namespace uWS;
using json = nlohmann::json;

int main() {
    Hub h;

    h.onMessage([](WebSocket<SERVER> *ws, char *message, size_t length, OpCode opCode) {
        json parsed = json::parse(message);
        ws->send(message, length, opCode);
    });

    if (h.listen(3000)) {
        h.run();
    }
}
```

I am getting this error when parsing the message (which is validated json):

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with unexpected exception of type nlohmann::detail::parse_error: [json.exception.parse_error.101] parse error at 37: syntax error - invalid literal; last read: '"{ \"happy\": true, \"pi\": 3.141 }"o'; expected end of input
```

So far I am stuck.

Thanks in advance.

Theo

Comment: This is a start, but we can't reproduce the problem with this code alone.

Comment: @tadman I edited the code

Comment: @TheoBouwman How do you send the message to this application? It would be nice if there was a bash command we could cut and paste to generate the same message. Looking at the error message `>\`'"{ \"happy\": true, \"pi\": 3.141 }"o'<` Seem like there are some extra characters in that message that make it not JSON. I would add code the prints out every character (with its ASCII code) to see what characters you got in the message.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any documentation for `uWebSockets` but presumably as `onMessage` has a `length` parameter `message` is not necessarily null terminated. You would therefore need to do:

```
json parsed = json::parse(message, length);
```

Comment: @TheoBouwman didn't compile? crashed? had the same problem as before? have you tried debugging?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to parse

```
"{ \"happy\": true, \"pi\": 3.141 }"o
```

There are several issues:

- the quotes around the JSON object seem unintentional - the result would be a string rather than an object
- the `o` after the string is unexpected, hence the error message; note the `o` is the 37th character read, hence `parse error at 37`